# Racket Scheme, Add 1 to the return value?

Tags: return, scheme, racket

Here is my program.

```
(define (golden n)
  (cond
  [(equal? n 0) 0]
  [else   (/  (+ 1 (golden (- n 1)))) ]
))
```

When n is zero, I want to return the result with 1 added to it, thus presenting the golden ratio... 1.61
Currently this program returns approximately 0.61 as a fraction -- I don't know how to add the one?

Answer (score 1):

Your approximation will calculate `golden ratio - 1`. So why not add the missing `1` *after* it returns? Also, it might be useful to convert the result to decimal values (instead of returning the result in fractions, as some interpreters do.) Let's write a helper for doing just that:

```
(define (golden n)
  (+ 1
     (exact->inexact
      (golden-helper n))))

(define (golden-helper n)
  (cond
    [(equal? n 0) 0]
    [else (/ 1 (+ 1 (golden-helper (- n 1))))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(golden 1000)
=> 1.618033988749895
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with out the helper function. The continued fraction of the golden ratio is phi = 1 + 1/(1+ 1/(1 + 1/ .. )). So in each step you can implement the recursion as `x_{n+1} = 1 + 1/x_n` (not `x_{n+1} = 1/(1+x_n)`), which includes the one automatically

```
(define (golden n)
  (cond
  [(equal? n 0) 1]
  [else   (+ 1 (/  1 (golden (- n 1)))) ]
 ))
```

You also need to change the return statement of the final recursion step to 1 as otherwise you get a division by zero.